# What is the differences between parse_server_sdk and parse_server?

Tags: flutter, parse-platform

I'm working with Parse Server, my task is to build a flutter application that using Parse SDK to communicate with the Parse Server. You can see [the Parse SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter) here, these are two packages, one is for Flutter, and another is for Dart. I don't know the difference between these two, and which one I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Flutter app you should use [Parse-SDK-Flutter](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter) package. In [Migration Guide](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/blob/release/2.0.0/docs/migrate-2-0-0.md) plugin developers provide this reason for moving from Dart to separate package:

`This was done in order to provide a dart package for the parse-server, while keeping maintenance simple. You can find both packages in the package directory.`.